# How to click on href using Acceptance testing w/ Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, href, acceptance

I have this content in the page source:

```
<td class="gridData" route="default" reset="0" urlparams="users index edit {userID}" label="Username">
<a href="/de/users/index/edit/userID/56">UM-Employee</a>
</td>
```

Any ideas on how to test this functionality to click on the user link?

Answer (score 3):

[click_link("UM-Employee")](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/1.1.1/Capybara/Node/Actions%3aclick_link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link text (as below) or an id-tag (which you would have to introduce into your HTML of course) to identify the link Capybara should follow.